# How can I change the height of the drawing circle automatic smooth slowly between the 3 height states nonstop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top:

```
public enum CircleHeight
    {
        Center, Bottom, Top
    };

    public CircleHeight circleheight;
    public bool draw = false;
```

In the Start:

```
void Start()
    {
        circleheight = CircleHeight.Center;
    }
```

In the Update:

```
void Update()
    {
        line.startWidth = lineThickness;
        line.endWidth = lineThickness;

        if (draw)
        {
            line.enabled = true;
            CreatePoints();
        }
        else
        {
            line.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Inside CreatePoints:

```
void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float z;

        float angle = 20;

        switch (circleheight)
        {
            case CircleHeight.Center:
                height = 0;
                break;
            case CircleHeight.Bottom:
                height = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.min).y + 0.1f;
                break;
            case CircleHeight.Top:
                height = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.max).y;
                break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, height, z));

            angle += (360f / segments + 1);
        }
    }
```

Inside the CreatePoints method I can change the enum states of the height.
But now I want to add a flag that if it will be true inside the CreatePoints it will change the height states automatic slowly smooth.

I tried to add inside the CreatePoints this part:

```
if(animateCircle)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime / 3;
            height = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, t);
            height = Mathf.Lerp(1, transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.min).y + 0.1f, t);
        }
```

And it does moving slowly from the top to bottom slowly but only once.
And it's moving between all 3 height states and not repeat automatic. So it's not working good yet as I wanted.

Comment: Do you want "bottom --(anim)--> top --(anim)--> bottom" or "bottom --(anim)--> top --(snap)--> bottom" or "bottom --(anim)--> <specific state height> (with snapped or animated return)"?

Comment: From center since center is the start default then first time from center to top then from top to bottom then from bottom to top and nonostop between top and bottom.

Comment: That's basically `"bottom --(anim)--> top --(anim)--> bottom"` with a non-endpoint staying state. Easy enough to do (but I need a real keyboard).

Comment: @Draco18s Edited my question with working solution. I'm not using yet the states but the idea is working. The way I'm doing it is fine ?

Comment: Put your solution in an answer, not the question. If it does what you want, then it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution:

At the top:

```
public enum CircleHeight
    {
        Center, Bottom, Top
    };

public CircleHeight circleheight;
[Range(0, 50)]
public int segments = 50;
private LineRenderer line;
private Renderer renderer;
private float Bottom;
private float Top;
private float t = 0f;
```

At the Start:

```
void Start()
    {
        circleheight = CircleHeight.Center;

        line = gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        Bottom = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.min).y + 0.1f;
        Top = transform.InverseTransformPoint(renderer.bounds.max).y + 0.1f;
    }
```

In Update:

```
void Update()
    {
      CreatePoints();
    }
```

In CreatePoints:

```
bool animStart = false;
void CreatePoints()
{
    float x;
    float z;

    float angle = 20;

    switch (circleheight)
    {
        case CircleHeight.Center:
            height = 0;
            break;
        case CircleHeight.Bottom:
            height = Bottom;
            break;
        case CircleHeight.Top:
            height = Top;
            break;
    }

    if (animateCircle)
    {
        if (animStart == false)
        {
            height = Mathf.Lerp(0, Top, t);
            t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (height == Top)
                animStart = true;
        }
        else
        {
            height = Mathf.Lerp(Bottom, Top, t);
            t += animationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (t > 1.0f)
            {
                float temp = Top;
                Top = Bottom;
                Bottom = temp;
                t = 0.0f;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
    {
        x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
        z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

        line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, height, z));

        angle += (360f / segments + 1);
    }
}
```

Since height start at the center height = 0 I added another flag animStart to move the circle first time to the top and then to start moving between top and bottom.

Now the drawn circle is moving smooth up and down between top and bottom smooth.